# ASA in multiple context: save config

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall

I have an ASA running 9.0(1) with four security contexts.  When we modify a context, our standard procedure is to do a "write mem" inside that context.  But sometimes we have to modify all the contexts in the same change window.  Can we just do a "write mem" from the system context and save all the context configs at once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do a write mem all:

> Saving All Context Configurations at the Same Time
>
> To save all context configurations at the same time, as well as the
>   system configuration, enter the following command in the system
>   execution space:
>
> Command Purpose write memory all [/noconfirm] Example: hostname# write
>   memory all /noconfirm Saves the running configuration to the startup
>   configuration for all contexts and the system configuration.
>
> If you do not enter the /noconfirm keyword, you see the following
>   prompt:
>
> Are you sure [Y/N]: After you enter Y, the ASA saves the system
>   configuration and each context. Context startup configurations can
>   reside on external servers. In this case, the ASA saves the
>   configuration back to the server you identified in the context URL,
>   except for an HTTP or HTTPS URL, which do not let you save the
>   configuration to the server.

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa90/configuration/guide/intro_start.html

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa90/configuration/guide/ha_contexts.html) from Cisco it says

> The running configuration that you edit in a configuration mode, or that is used in the **copy** or **write** commands, depends on your location. When you are in the system execution space, the running configuration consists only of the system configuration; when you are in a context, the running configuration consists only of that context. For example, you cannot view all running configurations (system plus all contexts) by entering the **show running-config** command. Only the current configuration displays.

It appears that you need to be in the context to write the changes.

**Edit:** The [getting started](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa90/configuration/guide/intro_start.html#wp1334476) documentation does tell you how to save multiple contexts at the same time by using **write memory all**